# get method from other JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two files

**sample1.js**

```
(function($){
    'use strict';

    var sample1_obj = {

        sample1_method : function(){

            alert("sample method 1");
        }

    }

})(jQuery);
```

**sample2.js**

```
(function($){
    'use strict';

    var sample2_obj = {

        sample2_method : function(){

            sample1_obj.sample1_method()

        }

    }

})(jQuery);
```

My Question is how to access the function/method inside the sample1_obj to the other file(**sample2.js**)?

Comment: Remove closure surrounding assignments of object

Answer (score 2):

"put" method to `window` object. When you can access it from `window.someMethod`. 
Or create just like that:

```
var simpleMethod1; //o there!
(function($){
    'use strict';

    var sample1_obj = {

        sample1_method : function(){

            alert("sample method 1");
        }

    }
    simpleMethod1 = sample1_obj.sample1_method;

})(jQuery);
```

`simpleMethod1()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

**script1.js**

`sample1_obj` is private to function. It wont be available unless it is make public

```
var sample1 = (function($) {
  'use strict';
  var sample1_obj = {
    sample1_method: function() {
      alert("sample method 1");
    }
  }
  return sample1_obj; // making it public
})(jQuery);
```

**script2.js**

```
var sample2 = (function($) {
  'use strict';
  var sample2_obj = {
    sample2_method: function() {
      sample1_obj.sample1_method()
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
sample1.sample1_method()
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <script src="jquery"></script>
  <script src="script1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="script2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/va0XCxUoiNef7nXKivT1?p=preview)

Comment: Why is `(function($){})(jQuery)` necessary?

Comment: @guest271314 the original question have IIFE